# How do I get my build to generate multi-line problem messages in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The compiler I'm currently using (GHC) to build my project generates multi-line messages for each error. I currently have a `tasks.json` file that specifies how to parse the output from GHC and present it to the VS Code problem panel. However, it only captures the first line of each message, as until now the VS Code problem panel only permits one line of text for each problem messgae.

The latest update to VS Code, 1.31, [promises multi-line messages in the problem panel](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_problems-panel). However, Microsoft does not explain how to get third-party build tools to generate multi-line messages. The regular expressions that match messages apparently cannot be made multi-line, and there does not seem to be any change to the `tasks.json` format.

How do I get multi-line messages from GHC and other tools to show up in the VS Code problem panel?